# How to convert Series to class float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am learning Python and right now I am trying to examine percent change in stock values from a database. However, one of the variables I am trying to examine is coming from a database which is of type Series. And whenever I try to convert into a float to use it for multiplication and division, I receive an error "TypeError: cannot convert the series to ". I have seen solutions that stated to use .astype(float), but that didn't work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime


path = "C:/Users/andre/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/SciKit-learn Tutorial/intraQuarter"

def Key_Stats(gather = "Total Debt/Equity (mrq)"): 
    statspath = path + '/_KeyStats'
    stock_list = [x[0] for x in os.walk(statspath)]
    counter = 0
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date','Unix','Folder','DE Ratio','Price',
                                 'Stock_pct_change','SP500','SP500_pct_change', 'Difference'])

    sp500_df = pd.read_csv("YAHOO-INDEX_GSPC.csv")
    ticker_list = []


    for each_dir in stock_list[1:]:
        each_file = os.listdir(each_dir)
        folder = each_dir.split("\\")[1]
        ticker_list.append(folder)

        #Reset starting point for each directory
        starting_stock_value = False
        starting_sp500_value = False

        if len(each_file) > 0:
            for file in each_file:
                date_stamp = datetime.strptime(file, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.html')
                unix_time = time.mktime(date_stamp.timetuple())
                full_file_path = each_dir + '/' + file

                file_content_source = open(full_file_path, 'r').read()

                try:
                    value = file_content_source.split(gather)[1].split('<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">')[1].split('</td>')[0]

                    try:
                        sp500_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                        row = sp500_df[(sp500_df['Date'] == sp500_date)] 
                        sp500_value = row['Adj Close']
                        print(type(sp500_value))
                        print(sp500_value)
                    except:    
                        sp500_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time-259200).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                        row = sp500_df[(sp500_df['Date'] == sp500_date)] 
                        sp500_value = row['Adj Close']

                    try:
                        stock_price = file_content_source.split('</small><big><b>')[1].split('</b></big>')[0]
                        if(stock_price.endswith('</span>')):
                           stock_price = stock_price.split('>')[1].split('</span')[0]
                    except IndexError:
                        try:
                            stock_price = file_content_source.split('</small><big><b>')[1].split('</span>')[0].split('>')[1]
                        except IndexError:   
                            try:
                                stock_price = file_content_source.split('<span id="yfs_')
                                seglist = [] #Created a list to store all the possible numbers that arise
                                for parts in stock_price:
                                    segment = parts.split('</span>')[0].split('>')[1]
                                    try:
                                        #The numbers are usually 4,5, or 6 characters in length and check if str is a number
                                        if((len(segment) == 4 or len(segment) == 5 or len(segment) == 6) and float(segment) >= 0):
                                            seglist.append(segment) #Add potential number to list
                                            stock_price = seglist[0] #Noticed the first number is usually the correct one
                                    except ValueError:
                                        pass
                            except IndexError:
                                print('Error in Folder:', folder, ' File: ', file, ' Stock Price=', stock_price)

                    #print('Folder:', folder, ' File', file, ' Stock Price: ', stock_price)

                    if not starting_stock_value:
                        starting_stock_value = float(stock_price)
                    if not starting_sp500_value:
                        starting_sp500_value = float(sp500_value)

                    #percentage change = (new-old)/old x 100
                    stock_pct_change = ((float(stock_price) - starting_stock_value) / starting_stock_value) * 100

   #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    #ERROR OCCURS HERE!!!!
                    sp500_pct_change = ((float(sp500_value) - starting_sp500_value) / starting_sp500_value) * 100

   #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    df = df.append({'Date': date_stamp,'Unix': unix_time,
                                    'Folder': folder,'DE Ratio': value,
                                    'Price': stock_price,
                                    'Stock_pct_change': stock_pct_change,
                                    'SP500': sp500_value,
                                    'SP500_pct_change': sp500_pct_change,
                                    'Difference': stock_pct_change-sp500_pct_change},
                                   ignore_index = True)
                except IndexError:
                    stock_price = file_content_source.split('<span id="yfs_')[5].split('</span>')[0].split('>')[1]
                    print('Error in Folder:', folder, ' File: ', file, "Value=", value, 'Stock Price=', stock_price)

    #Plot
    for each_ticker in ticker_list:
        try:
            plot_df = df[(df['Folder'] == each_ticker)]
            plot_df = plot_df.set_index(['Date'])

            plot_df['Difference'].plot(label = each_ticker)
            plt.legend()
        except:
            pass

    plt.show()


Key_Stats()
```

Error:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
2997    1131.130005
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
2947    1129.439941
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
2778    1198.680054
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Series([], Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\SciKit-learn Tutorial\Tutorial 6 - Playing with the Data (pct_change).py", line 103, in <module>
    Key_Stats()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\SciKit-learn Tutorial\Tutorial 6 - Playing with the Data (pct_change).py", line 83, in Key_Stats
    sp500_pct_change = ((float(sp500_value) - starting_sp500_value) / starting_sp500_value) * 100
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 93, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Comment: "use `.astype(float)`, but that didn't work for me" What exactly went wrong when you tried this?

Comment: on the line where I initialized sp500_value, i did sp500_value = row['Adj Close'].astype(float) but following line afterwards "print(type(sp500_value))" still says Pandas.core.series.Series and once it gets to the pct_change area highlighted where the error is, I get an error. "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()". I am new to this, so I may have put it in the wrong place.

Comment: Right now it's very hard for people here to offer more help because they cannot reproduce the error themselves (due to your code example relying on an external file). I'd suggest replacing `pd.read_csv("YAHOO-INDEX_GSPC.csv")` in your code example with a statement that directly creates a dataframe with some representative sample data (similar as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43093966/7306999)). Also I'd suggest removing any code that is not needed to reproduce the error. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here's a link to the csv file. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelgu95/machine-learning-stocks/master/YAHOO-INDEX_GSPC.csv

Comment: I was still unable to reproduce the error. When I run the code example (with CSV file available) neither any output nor an error message is generated.

Comment: Really! It's working for you? Did you make any changes to the code?

Comment: I didn't make any changes to the code. I don't think the code is running as intended though. Your code example seems to rely on additional data files (in a directory called `_KeyStats`). I suspect that when I run the code example the main for-loop never gets activated, because the aforementioned directory and its files are not available.

Comment: That's true. Luckily I just figured it out!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess we are working on the same project and on the same path. Here it is. I hope u understand where to insert this portion of the code

```
                try:
                    sp500_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    row = sp500_df[sp500_df["Date"] == sp500_date]
                    sp500_value = row["Adj Close"]
                    sp500_value1 = sp500_value.values[0]
                    print(sp500_value1)

                except:
                    sp500_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time-259200).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    row = sp500_df[sp500_df["Date"] == sp500_date]
                    sp500_value = row["Adj Close"]
                    sp500_value1 = sp500_value.values[0]
                    print(sp500_value1)
```